# Source for cooked milk and בשר חיה ועוף being אסור בהנאה

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk, birds, hanaah-benefit

בשר חיה ועוף cooked with milk are אסור to eat מדרבנן. Mistama, that means that the מחבר holds that it's מותר to get הנאה from this mixture. What I want to know is...

Are there any שיטות that hold you are not allowed to get הנאה out of בשר חיה ועוף cooked with milk בדרך בישול? Would it be more of an issue if it were cooked במזיד?

What about בשר טמאה cooked with milk? The רמ׳׳א in יו׳׳ד סי׳ פ׳׳ז ס׳ ג׳ says it's אסור מדרבנן to cook בשר טמאה with milk because of מראית עין. If they were already cooked is the mixture אסור בהנאה?

Sources please

Comment: "Mistama, that means that the מחבר holds that it's מותר to get הנאה from this mixture" Why do you assume this? Please clarify.

Comment: If מראית עין is an issue by bishul, why wouldn't it equivalently be an issue by selling?

Comment: Some rishonim thought we Paskin like the Tannaim that even Of and Chaya are Deorayta. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @loewian maybe if it was nikkar that it was cooked in milk.

Comment: Also, would you count as a שיטה the tanna of the first mishna in kol habasar (Chullin 104a)? (See also here: http://etzion.gush.net/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2011-10-08.php )

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume you mean if it wasn't nikkar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there seems to be those that forbid it - the Bach.

Have a look at the באר היטב in [סימן פז - באיזו בשר נוהג דין בשר בחלב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_15.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) who quotes the Bach that benefir would be forbidden מדרבנן.

Also, the Bach claims that fowl is a Torah prohibition.

> באר היטב  **(ג) ובהנאה**. כתב הש''ך אבל באכילה בלא"ה אסור מן התורה משום בשר טמא או חלב טמא ולא שייך לאסור משום בשר בחלב **והב"ח כתב דמדרבנן אסור משום בב"ח** ונ''מ לענין חנ''נ דס''ל להמחבר לקמן סי' צ''ב דאינו אלא בבשר בחלב וכן לענין חה''ל והשיג עליו הט''ז דהא עיקר הטעם לרבינו אפרים דמחמיר בבשר בחלב הוא מטעם שכ''א בפני עצמו מותר רק התערובות אסרו דנעשים גוף א' וזה לא שייך כאן במין א' טמא וכן חה''ל לא שייך כאן דלא גרע משאר איסור הבלוע ואין בו משום חה''ל וגם הש''ך חולק על הב''ח ע''ש: **(ד) מדרבנן**. והב''ח פסק דבשר **עוף בחלב הוא מן התורה** וחולק עליו הש''ך ומביא ל' הרמב''ם שהאומר בשר עוף בחלב אסור מן התורה עובר בבל תוסיף:‏